# Change in how Spring 5 handles null Beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So, I have the following application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AutonullApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AutonullApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  First first() {
    return null;
  }

  public class First {
  }

  @Service
  public class Second {

    private final First first;

    public Second(First first) {
      this.first = first;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void print() {
      System.out.println("First = " + first);
    }
  }

}
```

which tries to inject a bean of type `First` into a service of type `Second`. But the bean has a value of `null`. This code works fine in Spring Boot 1.5.10 (and so Spring 4), but fails in Spring Boot 2.0 (and Spring 5):

> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of constructor in
>   eu.plumbr.autonull.AutonullApplication$Second required a bean of type
>   'eu.plumbr.autonull.AutonullApplication$First' that could not be
>   found.

Is anybody aware of any mention of such change in the official documentation?

Comment: Moving from 1.5.10 to 2.0.0 I also noticed that my application startup fails with "Field fieldName in com.example.MyService required a bean of type 'com.example.MyBean' that could not be found" in case the Bean returns null.

Comment: I filed this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12563

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is a breaking change in Spring Framework 5. Arguably, such setup is weird and we wanted to tighten those rules a little bit.

If you request to inject `First` and you provide `null`, then it's more consistent to consider that bean isn't provided. You can then query the context for the presence of `First`. @spencergibb already explained how you can use `Optional`, or you can use `ObjectProvider<First>` as an injection point:

```
@Service
public class Second {

    private final First first;

    public Second(ObjectProvider<First> first) {
        this.first = first.getIfAvailable(); // return null
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any issue in Spring tracker and/or change log entry concerning this breaking change in Spring Framework?

Comment: Why are you doing this for no good reason? Null has a good reason to exist!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The java 8, null-safe way would be to use the `Optional` class.

```
@Service
public class Second {

  private final Optional<First> first;

  public Second(Optional<First> first) {
    this.first = first;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void print() {
    System.out.println("First = " + first.orElse(null));
  }
}
```