# Upgrade from Spring 4 to Spring 5 and run into @Autowired enforcement issue. Any workaround please?

Tags: spring, autowired

I am upgrading our app from spring 4 to spring 5. The app has a third party dependency library that we can not touch. This library is using spring 4 and one of its beans is autowiring a null bean instance. This works fine in spring 4 but I got the following exception in spring 5:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'LibraryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '_beanDoesntExist'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'x.y.z.LibraryService$BeanDoesntExist' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The following is a demo of such a `@Autowired` usage in the library that would trigger the exception above in spring 5(but worked fine in spring 4):

```
@Service
public class LibraryService
{
    @Autowired
    private BeanDoesntExist _beanDoesntExist;

    static class BeanDoesntExist {

    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public BeanDoesntExist beanDoesntExist() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems in spring 5, a check is added: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#L1293-L1296

```
            if (result instanceof NullBean) {
                if (isRequired(descriptor)) {
                    raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(type, descriptor.getResolvableType(), descriptor);
                }
```

This check would enforce `@Autowired` to always get not null instance back if `required=true` which is the default.

By comparision, in spring 4, there is no such enforcement check and the following code would simply return null in my case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#L1131-L1132

```
            return (instanceCandidate instanceof Class ?
                    descriptor.resolveCandidate(autowiredBeanName, type, this) : instanceCandidate);
```

Since I can't touch the library code, I wonder how can I get around the @Autowired enforcement in spring 5? My app can't be started up with this enforcement in place.

Comment: Could you feed the library the dependency it needs on the context? Why does the library have a class with a dependency that doesn't get used?

Comment: I simplified the logic inside `beanDoesntExist()` for demo purpose. In reality, it is doing a bunch of things and under some condition, it is returning null. I don't know how to feed the library on the context. I mean LibraryService in this case won't be created successfully and the app fails to launch as a result, and attempt to set the dependency might be too late.

Comment: could you create a @Bean instance of `BeanDoesntExist` or a subclass  so it does not fail anymore?

Comment: I thought about that but that would require a qualifier since we now have two beans of the same type, and my bean would never gets used because of the qualifier. Also, even if my bean gets used, that would break the logic in the library since the library has some code that handles the `_beanDoesntExist` being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a breaking change in Spring 5 and has been covered here:

[Change in how Spring 5 handles null Beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044770/change-in-how-spring-5-handles-null-beans)

Using Optional or ObjectProvider seems to be a viable workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the link which shows this is a known issue in spring 4 to 5 migration. The main problem is we can't touch this library so we can't change to use Optional or @Autowired(required = false) etc.