# How do I configure a @Bean if it's accepted to fail initialisation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some code that initialises a Google Authentication `IdTokenProvider` (the type of object is unrelated to my question). However, given the current state of my application, it's not the end of the world if the provider fails to initialise. For example:

```java
@Configuration
public class GoogleConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public IdTokenProvider idTokenProvider() {
    // this can throw
    return GoogleAuthUtils.getIdTokenProvider();
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeConsumer {

  private IdTokenProvider idTokenProvider;

  @Autowired(required = false)
  public void setIdTokenProvider(IdTokenProvider idTokenProvider) {
    this.idTokenProvider = idTokenProvider;
  }

  //...magic
}
```

One possible solution (which works), is to wrap the throwing code and return `null`, e.g.

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class GoogleConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public IdTokenProvider idTokenProvider() {
    try {
      return GoogleAuthUtils.getIdTokenProvider();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Failed to create an 'IdTokenProvider'", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it a good pattern to return `null` beans. I believe spring registers the bean, but its value is actually `null` rather than an instance of `IdTokenProvider`. Is there a way to avoid registering the bean if it fails instantiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Change in how Spring 5 handles null Beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044770/change-in-how-spring-5-handles-null-beans), Spring 5 will not register the (null) bean. Since your code treats it as optional, it will work fine.

You may want to consider [conditional bean creation](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/), to register the bean only when the authentication provider is valid (the success case).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this changed in spring 5. I cannot use any meaningful condition (I think) since the class is there. It's just the call to that class that fails, e.g. your credentials might be missing in the environment or similar.