# How to mock a ObjectProvider<XXX> that is autowired?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

I am doing a migration from Spring 4.x to 5.x and am following the recommendation to wrap the object with an ObjectProvider to handle beans that return null: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393682/10863988

This is the class set up I have:

```
class ConfigurationClass{
  @Autowired
  private ObjectProvider<MyObject> myObject;

  public SomeOtherClass getSomeOtherClass() {
    return new SomeOtherClass(myObject.getIfAvailable());
  }
}
```

```
class TestSomeOtherClass {
  @Mock
  MyObject myObject;
  
  @InjectMocks
  ConfigurationClass;

  SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

  public void setup() {
    this.someOtherClass = spy(configuration.getSomeOtherClass());
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run this test. the `myObject` in the `ConfigurationClass` returns a null pointer exception.

I've tried adding this to the `TestSomeOtherClass` but I still can't seem to mock the `ObjectProvider<MyObject>`:

```
class TestSomeOtherClass {
  @Mock
  MyObject myObject;

  @Mock
  ObjectProvider<MyObject> myObjectObjectProvider;

  @InjectMocks
  ConfigurationClass;

  SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;

  public void setup() {
    doReturn(myObject).when(myObjectObjectProvider).getIfAvailable();
    this.someOtherClass = spy(configuration.getSomeOtherClass());
  }
}
```

Any advice on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not tell Mockito to handle it's annotations (`@Mock`, `@InjectMocks`) anywhere in your code, so they do not have any effect. By default all non-primitive fields in Java are initialized as `null` - that's where the `NullPointerException` comes from.

---

**openMocks/initMocks method**

Depending on the version of Mockito you're using, you need to call `initMocks()` or `openMocks()` static method from the `MockitoAnnotations` class:

```java
AutoCloseable openMocks;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    // the line below is where the magic happens
    openMocks = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    doReturn(myObject).when(myObjectObjectProvider)
                      .getIfAvailable();
    someOtherClass = spy(configuration.getSomeOtherClass());
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws Exception {
    openMocks.close();
}

@Test
void test() {
    assertNotNull(someOtherClass);
}
```

---

**@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)**

You can also use the `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` annotation over your class and it has the same effect as the methods described above.

---

You can find both approaches tested in a [GitHub repository I've created](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/tree/73297910/spring-boot-module/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz) (all tests pass).