# Returning null in Bean annotated method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, null-object-pattern

I have a web filter that I only want to execute when debug level is enabled. I was trying to implement a dummy filter to return to conform to Null Object pattern but I was getting many errors and lost hours. The solution below seems to work seamlessly but I wonder what happens if `@Bean` method returns null? Is this safe?

```
   @Bean
    WebFilter payloadFilter() {
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            return new PayloadFilter();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not allowed: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49044770/685806

Comment: You get a null bean and places that directly reference it will fail. Instead of returning null why not just return a noop filter instead?

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to return `null` in IoC frameworks like Spring, because you don't know where and how your beans are used.

Comment: I don't understand that _I was trying to implement a dummy filter to return to conform to Null Object pattern but I was getting many errors and lost hours._ A dummy filter should just need to implement `WebFilter.filter()` as `return chain.filter(exchange);`

Answer (score 1):

Of course, returning null is not a good idea, you should avoid it.
I don't know how logging in your application is controlled, but if you setup logging level via application.yml, I would do something like this:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "logging.level", name = "com.example.config", havingValue = "DEBUG")
public WebFilter payloadFilter() {
    return new PayloadFilter();
}
```